# My SVG is overriding my background color on mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

When I test on other devices and browsers, my blue background color (#3838be) shows behind my animated svg, but on safari mobile, it turns my background white.

I've tried containing the svg in a div with my background color, but it doesn't work. I've tried rearranging where my svg is placed in my code, but it doesnt work either

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3838be, #5a5af2);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  font-family: europa, sans-serif;
}

.blob {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: #a5b11e;
  width: 50vmax;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="blob">
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 310 350">
  <path d="M156.4,339.5c31.8-2.5,59.4-26.8,80.2-48.5c28.3-29.5,40.5-47,56.1-85.1c14-34.3,20.7-75.6,2.3-111  c-18.1-34.8-55.7-58-90.4-72.3c-11.7-4.8-24.1-8.8-36.8-11.5l-0.9-0.9l-0.6,0.6c-27.7-5.8-56.6-6-82.4,3c-38.8,13.6-64,48.8-66.8,90.3c-3,43.9,17.8,88.3,33.7,128.8c5.3,13.5,10.4,27.1,14.9,40.9C77.5,309.9,111,343,156.4,339.5z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Here is what it looks like in mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwg0v.jpg)

biancat.co is my website if you want to see what it is supposed to look like

Comment: What version of Safari/iOS are you running? I just tried running your example on jsfiddle in Safari 11.3 and it worked fine with the blue background, at this URL: https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/tsq62kch/

Comment: @RobKwasowski It seems to work well in browsers, but not mobile. Im running iOS 12.3.1.

Comment: Just checked @RobKwasowski's jsfiddle on Safari mobile and it's working fine. From your image it seams as if the browser you are using doesn't understand linear-gradient. Use a plain color to check this hypothesis.

Comment: Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @enxaneta it works fine on fiddle but I'm not sure why it specifically doesnt work on Safari on my iPad and iPhone XR. I also tried to do the plain color, but it doesnt work still.

Comment: @RobKwasowski It isnt working still..

Comment: In this case maybe your svg have a background defined. Try adding `svg{background:none}`